# LastRecordsumisnotincluding in Crystalreports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am adding running total for the job cost and report contains multiple same jobrecords and i need to add single value for each job. i have added below condition in the evaluate formula unfortunately it is not including the lastrecord total.

if {PKsh_JobMaterialListRepair;1.job}<>next({PKsh_JobMaterialListRepair;1.job}) then
true

Comment: Since you're new to stackoverflow, don't forget to green-check the response that best-answers your question :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
OnFirstRecord or 
{PKsh_JobMaterialListRepair;1.job}<>previous({PKsh_JobMaterialListRepair;1.job})
```

(By the way, your statement results in a boolean, so you don't need to include the `if() then true` clause.)

Comment: +1 It's probably worth mentioning that Nag's formula doesn't work for the last record because the value of `next({PKsh_JobMaterialListRepair;1.job})` is NULL, and therefore the formula evaluates as NULL.

Comment: @Mark: True. I just thought I would keep it simple.